# Embed webpart cannot find file

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm using the Embed webpart and have problems with using the right url or storing the data on the right place.
I use the next iframe:

```
<iframe src="https://******.sharepoint.com/SiteAssets/Webmap/index.aspx#11/52.1/5.62" width="100%" height="470"></iframe>
```

I have uploaded the map Webmap with its content on SiteAssets.
Webmap consists, besides index.aspx, the following subdirectories: css, data, images, js, legend, markers, webfonts. 
The error message of the webpart is "File not found"

(The message is translated by me in English so maybe it is slightly different ie Cannot find file) 
Where should I put the Webmap map so I can use a working URL in the Webpart?
Please help, cannot find information about this.

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to say a bit more about web map? Is that a custom web part or a page? Commonly we use embed web part to display pages from other sites directly. And we do not use it to embed custom web parts/solutions. A bit more information about your goal will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Site Assets should be fine. 
Make sure all files are located on the same site collection though. 
Also, if you insert the URL from the iframe to web browser and open console - does it throw any errors?

Comment: https://[Name].sharepoint.com/SiteAssets/Webmap/

Comment: If I insert https://[Name].sharepoint.com/SiteAssets/Webmap/ it opens the Webmap folder, I cannot open the index.aspx file with the browser from here
The same if I change the src in the iframe to https://[Name].sharepoint.com/SiteAssets/Webmap/
If I open /Webmap/index.html#11/52.1/5.62 on my local filesystem the content is shown (I have to change html to aspx to let it work on the server).
Could it be that the subfolders below Webmap cannot be found, do I needsomething like runat or so?